# How to read stock quantity of a vartaion product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to store stock quantity of product & its variations along with Product_id(Post ID) in a custom table after the creation of a new product. for this i am using 'transition_post_status' hook & for reading the stock value i am using wp_postmeta table `$prodcut_qty = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_stock');`.

**Suppose that there is product A(stock quantity = 10) & A1 (stock quantity = 10) ,A2(stock quantity = 20),A3(stock quantity = 30) are variations of A.So i want to store all the above details in custom table.**

```
My DB schema is {post_id bigint (20), user_id bigint (20), stock_quantity int (11),log_date DATE}
```

I am unable to read stock values for product variation.
My Code is -

```
function insert_custom_table($new_status, $old_status, $post ) 
{
    
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;
    
    if(isset($post->ID))
    {
        $current_post = $post->ID;
    }
   wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'product' ) {
        return;
    }else{

            if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status ){
                //Check if someone published a post first time.
                return;
            }else{

                $prodcut_qty = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_stock');
               //Unable to read stock values for product variations.
                    
            }

    }      
    $stock_notes = 'New Stock';
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_woocommerce_stock_custom', array( 'post_ID' => $current_post, 'user_ID' => $user_id, 'stock_quantity'=> $prodcut_qty ,'notes'=> $stock_notes) );


}
```

I am using woocommerce 5.5.2

**Update :**

I found that if we want to read postmeta table immediate after publish the post,for this type of task hook [added_post_meta](http://hookr.io/actions/added_post_meta/) works fine.

Comment: What hook you use ? You should use woocommerce_update_product hook http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_update_product/

Comment: @MartinMirchev i am using transition_post_status' hook & i am Checking post type as 'product' like this  $post->post_type !== 'product'

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and this should do the trick

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'wc_updated_product_stock_callback' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_set_stock', 'wc_updated_product_stock_callback' );

function wc_updated_product_stock_callback( $product_id ) {
    // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $stock_qty    = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // Here add your functionality
    
    error_log('Quantity is '.$stock_qty ); // For testing before working with DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks martin, I tested this hook 'woocommerce_product_set_stock' it is always work when the stock value is changed. Due to this value stored in my custom master table is also changed.
I don't want to update my master table after every transaction.So that i was asking for reading stock value on product creation time.
I am trying to create a inventory check system which will monitor the behavior of inbuilt stock management of WooCommerce

Comment: Hi Martin, I found the hook 'added_post_meta' for read stock quantity of a variation product in woocommerce.It is working fine.Thanks for idea of error_log().

Answer (score 0):

**I got the solution:**

I found that if we want to read postmeta table immediate after publish the post,for this type of task hook added_post_meta works fine.

**I modified my previous code**

```
function insert_custom_table($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' && get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish')
        {
            $product_id = $post_id;
            $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'woocommerce_stock_master';
            if(!$product_id)
            {
                return;
            }  

            wp_get_current_user();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;

            // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
            // get product type
            // get stock _manage  
            if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )){
                 //$product_id = $product->get_id(); 
                
                $variations = $product->get_children(); // get variations
                foreach ($variations as $variations_value) {
                    $single_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variations_value);
                    $single_variation_stock = $single_variation->get_stock_quantity();
                    
                    // insert into db 
                   
                }
           }
           if ($product->is_type( 'simple' )){
                if($manage_stock == 'yes')
                {
                  //insert in to db
                }
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }
        error_log('Quantity is '.$stock_qty);  
    }
    add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'insert_custom_table',10,4);
```

Comment: i used  added_post_meta action hook.